# C code not working properly

Tags: c, int

I'm just learning how to code in C, It's my first non-web language and it's not off to a good start.

I have the following code:

```
//
//  main.c
//  Greeting
//
//  Created by Austen on 2013-06-27.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Austen. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int confirm[100];
    char name[100];
    char mood[100];

    printf( "Please enter your name: " );
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf( "Hey there, %s . How are you? ", name);
    scanf("%s", mood);
    printf("Oh, you are %s?. Enter 1 or 0: ", mood);
    scanf("%i", confirm);
    if (confirm == 1) {
        printf("Oh good!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Make up your mind");
    }
    getchar();
    return(0);

}
```

For some reason I just can't get it to work, I've had to change a few things in order for Xcode to stop moaning at me for so many reasons.
It's giving me a

```
warning: Comparison between pointer and integer int* and int
```

When I run it, even if I enter 1, it tells me to make up my mind.

Any help would be great, just so I know better next time. It's probably something really simple.

Comment: get integer from `scanf`, give it argument "%d".

Comment: `confirm` should not be an array. Just `int confirm;`

Comment: For future reference, it's useful if you can provide the full warning message copied and pasted from the output. C is fiddly, and often the act of reading/formating a warning makes you realize something you've been ignoring. Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: `int confirm[100];` --  you don't need 100 confirmations; one will do.

Comment: @MYMNeo `%i` is fine ... it allows numbers in octal or hex form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create an array to hold an answer for `confirm`, a normal `int` will do:

```
int confirm;
```

But as `scanf` expects a pointer you need to pass its address like so:

```
scanf("%d", &confirm);
```

Finally, this - `scanf("%i", confirm);` should actually be this - `scanf("%d", &confirm);`.

`%d` is the standard formatting character for integer variables.

After that, everything compiled fine.

C is always pass by value, so there's no way for `scanf` to store the value you enter in the variable provided, unless it reaches inside memory where it resides and writes it to memory directly.

That's why it asks for the memory address of the variable, rather than the variable itself (you provide the address of something by prepending `&` to it).

Arrays are already treated as addresses (pointers to be more precise and pointers store the address of something) when passed as arguments to a function which is why you don't do it for them.

Some information on pointers and arrays [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/).

Comment: But can you explain why I need to add the &?

Comment: That's because you need to pass a pointer to the memory address of `confirm`, and that's what the `&` operator does.

Comment: @Nobilis You missed the & in the scanf statement

Comment: @Austen Patterson C is always pass by value, so there's no way for `scanf` to store the value you enter in the variable provided, **unless** it reaches inside memory where it resides and writes it to memory directly. That's why it asks for the memory address of the variable, rather than the variable itself (you provide the address of something by appending `&` to it, arrays are already treated as addresses which is why you don't do it for them).
Read up on pointers for more information :)

Comment: @Austen Patterson I've added it in the answer body.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get that warning is because you're comparing an array of 100 integers to 1 integer. The correct code would be something like this

```
if (confirm[0] == 1)
```

or even easier

```
int confirm;
scanf("%d", &confirm);
if (confirm == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%d` for integers (for confirm)

Confirm is declared as an array, but you just want a plain integer. Remove the [100] after `confirm` in the declaration. It should just be;

```
int confirm;
```

The warning you got was because `confirm` was an array and it tried to compare the array's base address(confirm) to an integer value (1).

Whenever you declare an array, the base address of that array is available in the array name.(Eg. `confirm` here)

Replace the `scanf` line which takes `confirm` with

```
scanf("%d",&confirm);
```

it should work fine then

Comment: Still getting the same problem =/

Comment: There was one more error.... confirm was declared as an array .... see the answer again